# How to assign matrix input to symbolic equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, symlink

I calculated a very long equation symbolically. Now I am trying to use that equation with matrix inputs. I will write a code that illustrates what I want to do.

```
syms a b c d real;
y=a+2b+c^2;

a=[1 2 3 4 5];
b=[1 3 5 6 7];
c=[1 5 2 3 7];
```

I want to calculate y as matrix. I read about subs function but I couldnt understand how can I implement that for matrix input.

Answer (score 0):

```
syms a b c d real;
syms y(a,b,c);
y(a,b,c)=a+(2*b)+(c^2);

e=[1 2 3 4 5];
f=[1 3 5 6 7];
g=[1 5 2 3 7];

y(e,f,g)  % output will be in command window
```

I hope this helps